# Share markdown snippets across multiple cells and jupyter notebooks

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

How can I include a markdown snippet across multiple cells, and multiple notebooks?

Ideally when I change the snippet it will update everywhere it is included.

Answer (score 1):

Tukushan,

http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/storemagic.html

Try the `%store` command.  I couldn't get it to work with functions or with markdown, so I stored a markdown snippet as text, then read it with `%store -r <variable>` in a new notebook.

example:

in notebook_1:

`title_var = "# Re-Useable Title"`

`%store title_var`

> Stored 'title_var' (str)

in notebook_2:

`%store -r title_var`